# How to call a ruby method when :onchange event is triggered (ruby on rails 4)?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am pretty new to ruby on rails...
On my `_form.html.erb` I have a `collection_select` field, which is populated from a Model called Product. The Product's table columns are `id, name, and price`. Once I select an item (product) from the collection I would like to populate a text field with the price of the selected product.

So far I have the following code IOT trigger an event when selecting an item:

```
<%= collection_select( :warehouse, :product_id, Product.all, :id, :name, {}, {:onchange => "alert('Hello World');"} )%>
```

How can I call a ruby method which would let me populate the text_field with the corresponding price for the selected product?

For the method I was thinking something like...

```
def set_price
      @price = Product.find(params[:id]).price
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The erb snippet

```
<%= collection_select( :warehouse, :product_id, Product.all, :id, :name, {}, {:onchange => "alert('Hello World');"} )%>
```

generates the html snippet like this

```
<select name="warehouse[product_id]" onchange="alert('Hello World');">
  <option value="1">Product 1</option>
  <option value="2">Product 2</option>
  ...
</select>
```

So the content of `onchange` is just a piece of javascript, which runs on browsers. There is no way to let `onchange` run ruby code directly. All you can do is send an AJAX request in `onchange`, and let your Rails application respond to that request.

Comment: Is there another way of performing this without AJAX. In c# I was able to perform this task handling the controls events through callbacks. Is it possible to handle the collection_select events through callbacks in ruby? If not what is the best practice for achieving the required?

Comment: `ASP.net`'s callback system is based on AJAX too (if you choose javascript as your client side scripting language). See [https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178208.aspx](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178208.aspx) for more information.

Comment: You're absolutely right. I'm going to try that approach. Thanks so much for your help  Aetherus